# Symmetric non-degenerate bilinear forms over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules, bilinear-form

Consider the four non-degenerate symmetric bilinear forms over $\mathbb{Q}$ given be the matrices
$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0\\ 0&1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0\\ 0&-1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
-1&0\\ 0&1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ and $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
-1&0\\ 0&-1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.
Considered over $\mathbb{Z}$ these matrices become unimodular symmetric bilinear forms.

I want to classify all unimodular symmetric bilinear forms over $\mathbb{Z}$, which are, considered over $\mathbb{Q}$ equivalent to one of the given forms above.

Can somebody help me?